# Copying files during compilation process

Tags: java, ruby, compilation, rake, buildr

I use builder for my buildprocess.

I have some java classes in my src directory as well as some *.qvto files. These files just need to be copied to target/classes. However, this should be done as part of the compilation process, as these files represent some part of code that does not need to be compiled. Currently, I am stuck and do not know how to proceed.

My compilation looks like this at the moment:

```
compile.with LIBS, projects('BPEL', 'ProcessModel', 'SharedState_ebBP')
```

However, I want to copy all *.qvto files from src/main/java to target/classes. And only, if they have been changed. Do you have an idea, how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the Apache `buildr` tool, then I think the solution is to move the files to src/main/resources and they will be copied automatically by the "compile" step.

The [buildr Quick Start](http://buildr.apache.org/quick_start.html) page explains this.

Comment: This gave me the hint. I used the filter facility to achieve it. 


# compile with dependencies to libs and other projects

    compile do

      # copy qvto files

      filter(_'src/main/java').into(_'target/classes').include('*.qvto').run

    end

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Maven as a building tool it needs to move all `.qvto` files to `src/main/resources` directory.